# Virtualbox: resolvconf in ubuntu 12.04 host breaks DNS in WinXP guest

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, dns

[x-post to [vbox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=49519)]

Virtualbox: Ubuntu 12.04 host, WinXP SP3 guest.

The recent change in DNS handling in Ubuntu 12.04 is described [here](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/). It means that a NAT'ed WinXP host will receive a 127.0.0.1 DNS server IP, which prevents DNS from working out-of-the-box in the guest.

A workaround is to set the DNS Server(s) manually in the guest every time.

What is the recommended virtualbox setup for hosts running resolvconf (assuming the host does not have a static IP) to make DNS work seamlessly in the guest?

Answer (score 2):

From https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=49519#p226989

Run on the host:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```